# Which is the right formula to evaluate the diameter of a divergent gaussian beam at a distance r?

Tags: optics

Good morning,
I have to evaluate the diameter of a gaussian beam at a distance $r$ which has a divergence $\theta$ and a starting diameter $d_0$.
I found these three ways:

1)
$
d_f=d_0+r\tan(\theta)
$

2)$d_f=d_0+2r\tan(\theta/2)$

3)$d_f=d_0+r\theta$

I was wondering which is the right one between these three formulas and if they are different approximations of the same formula.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be seen as a matter of how you define the divergence angle $\theta$. Different authors seem to define it slightly differently, however in practice this is rarely an issue since $\theta$ is typically small enough that $2\tan(\theta/2) \approx \tan(\theta) \approx \theta$.

The Gaussian beam as a solution to the paraxial Helmholtz equation has the intensity
$$I(\rho, z) = I_0 \left[\frac{W_0}{W(z)}\right]^2 \exp \left[-\frac{2\rho^2}{W^2(z)}\right],$$
$$W(z) = W_0 \sqrt{1 + (z/z_0)^2},$$
$$W_0 = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda z_0}{\pi}},$$
where $\rho$ is the distance from the beam axis, $z$ is the position along the beam axis, $W_0$ is called the waist radius and $z_0$ the Rayleigh range (from Saleh & Teich). The fraction of the power of the beam contained by a circle of radius $\rho$ about the beam that is a distance $z$ away from the beam waist is
$$1 - \exp \left[-\frac{2\rho^2}{W^2(z)}\right].$$
If you define the beam diameter (as is usually done) as the diameter containing $1 - e^{-2}$ of the power, then the beam diameter is
$$D(z) = 2W(z) = 2W_0 \sqrt{1 + (z/z_0)^2} = D_0 \sqrt{1 + (z/z_0)^2}$$
with $D_0 = 2W_0$. Far away from the beam waist ($z \gg z_0$), we have
$$D(z) \approx D_0 \frac{z}{z_0}.$$
This diameter is defined by a cone along the beam axis with the vertex at the center of the beam. The half-angle of this cone is
$$ \theta_0 = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{W_0}{z_0}\right) $$

Now, if we define the divergence to be the full vertex angle of this cone, i.e. $\theta = 2\theta_0$,
$$ D(z) = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(2\frac{W_0}{z_0}z\right)^2} = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(2z\tan\theta_0\right)^2} = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left[2z\tan(\theta/2)\right]^2} $$

If we define the divergence as $\theta = \tan^{-1}(D_0/z_0)$ (although I don't see an obvious reason for doing so),
$$ D(z) = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(\frac{D_0}{z_0}z\right)^2} = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(z\tan\theta\right)^2} $$

If we define the divergence as $\theta = D_0/z_0$ so that $D(z) \approx \theta z$ for $z\gg z_0$ (this is twice the definition in Saleh & Teich),
$$ D(z) = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(\frac{D_0}{z_0}z\right)^2} = \sqrt{D_0^2 + \left(\theta z\right)^2}. $$

I believe the formulas you gave are approximations for these expressions that are valid for $z \approx 0$ and $z \gg z_0$.

Comment: Many thanks fot this high quality answer!
Now it's all clear to me.
It seems you're very familiar with gaussian beams so I have another little question:
I have this formula for evaluate power of a gaussian beam trasmitted through an aperture having diameter $d$ if I have the waist diamater containing 63% of the power: $T_{63}=1-e^{-(\frac{d}{w})^2}$. If I have the diameter 86% one the formula became $T_{86}=1-e^{-(\frac{d}{2w})^2}$. Do you know the origin of this difference by a square root of 2? Many thanks again!

Comment: What does $T$ refer to exactly?

Comment: I know the $d_{63}$ or $d_{86}$ diameter  which are the value of the diameter of the beam where I can found $63/%$ or $86/%$ of the power respectively. I need to know how much power pass from an aperture, so $T$ is intended as transmitted power i guess. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't that mean $T_{63} = 0.63$ and $T_{86} = 0.86$?

Comment: Sorry for this, I try to explain me better. I know that the diameter value of my gaussian beam where I have the $86$ % of the power is e.g. $6 mm$. I have to compute the power which pass through an aperture e.g. of $7 mm$. I should go for the $T_{86}$ formula. I was wondering why I have to use two different formulas if I have the $d_{86}$ or $d_{63}$ and how do you think about this. Yes, $T_{63}=0.63$ of the power. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm still confused about this, you have the aperture diameter, and $d_{86}$ or $d_{63}$. You want to calculate the transmission. I'm guessing $d$ in your equations is referring to the aperture diameter. Where are $d_{86}$ and $d_{63}$? Are they related to $w$, or does $w$ indicate beam radius/diameter?

The aperture diameter that transmits 86% (or $1 - e^{-2}$) of the power is $2W(z)$, as explained in my answer. The aperture diameter that transmits 63% (or $1 - e^{-1}$) of the power is found by solving $1 - e^{-D^2/(2W^2(z))} = 1 - e^{-1}$, which gives $\sqrt{2}W(z)$. Maybe this will help.

Comment: The full situation is a gaussian laser's beam and about this beam I know the output diameter which in one case is the diameter where I found 63% of the power and 86% in the other
Now, 100mm after the output I have an aperture having diameter of 7mm. I need to know how much power pass this aperture. 
I evaluate the new diamater of my beam after 100mm of propagation as you said in your answer. So I have a new diameter obtained from the 63% or 86% one respectively. The question is: why I have to use two different formulas for the power through the aperture depending by the initial 63% or 86%?

Comment: I need to evaluate the diameter at 100 mm to replace it in the exponential formula as $w$.

Comment: And when I'm referring to "power through the aperture" I think it's better say "the percentage of the power passing the aperture".

Comment: I think I understand, however I get slightly different formulas than the ones you have. As I explained in my comment above, the 86% transmission diameter is $2W(z)$ and the 63% transmission diameter is $\sqrt{2}W(z)$. If $w$ denotes these diameters, substituting $W(z)=w/2$ and $W(z)=w/\sqrt{2}$, respectively, in the the power transmission formula $1-\exp(D^2/2W^2(z))$, gives $1-\exp(2D^2/w^2)$ for the 86% transmission diameter and $1-\exp(D^2/w^2)$ for 63%. The formula you gave with the 86% transmission diameter is different however, and I don't know why.

Comment: I think we are close to the point. Since it's not easy to understand my issue I've posted the numerical problem here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490151/optical-power-through-a-circular-aperture
If you want you can take a glance at it.

The actual problem is to get the diameter I need starting from the 63% or 86% with the proper formula.